# How to query database if we need to query with an array of id's in jsp?

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, select-query, multiple-select-query

After selecting some products a user clicked on proceed button. Now I need to display the selected data on next page. I was successful in getting the id's of selected data using the following code.

```
String[] array = request.getParameterValues("arrayid");
```

Now I need to query mysql database using "select * from table where id=?"
I can use this query in a loop. But is there any other or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] array = request.getParameterValues("arrayid");    
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE id IN ?"; 
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setArray(1,con.createArrayOf("CHAR", array));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood this logic. But I get an error 'java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException' while using the createArrayOf() method.

I used another logic to solve my issue. Following link explains that
[Click Here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2)

Answer (score 2):

Use IN keyword while selecting as select * from table where id IN(comma separated ids)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to query for a set of IDs in a table, the other answers correctly refer you to SQL's `IN` keyword.  However if you're asking specifically how to do it in Java, JDBC's [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), which is the generally recommended way of executing queries in Java, does not make constructing these `IN` statements easy.  I posted a suggested way to address this issue *reasonably* cleanly here: [Can PreparedStatement.addBatch() be used for SELECT queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899543/in-java-can-preparedstatement-addbatch-be-used-for-select-queries/20181662#20181662)