# Can prepareStatement do the same thing like Statement?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

My DB is Oracle.
I know `Statement` can mix SQL sentences(insert or delete or update) into one single batch. Here is my code.

```
DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
Connection c = db.getConn();
Statement s = null ;


try
{ 
    String sql = "insert into t1(id, name) values ('10', 'apple')";
    String sql1 = "insert into t1(id, name) values ('14', 'pie')";
    String sql2 = "delete from t1 where id = '10'";
    s = c.createStatement();

    s.addBatch(sql);
    s.addBatch(sql1);
    s.addBatch(sql2);

    int[] re = s.executeBatch();...
```

My question is can `PreparedStatement` do this? and how?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7899543/180100) might help

Comment: `PreparedStatement` extends `Statement`, and stores the precompiled SQL Statement. So it works with same syntax. Do you see any issue?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: so how would you use a *single* `PreparedStatement` to run *different* SQL statements in a batch?

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar one `PreparedStatement` can only store one precompiled SQL Statment. But I have two one is `insert` and the other is `delete`. `PreparedStatement.addBatch()` cannot add any parameter.

Comment: @Ron and a_horse_with_no_name, I read it wrong. !! Sorry abt tht!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch by [PreparedStatement.addBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and you can execute it by [PreparedStatement.executeBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29)

For more about PreparedStatement you can look into [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Now if i am not wrong you want to do something like this:

```
public void save(List<Entity> elements) throws SQLException {
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        Element element= elements.get(i);
        statement.setString(1, element.getProperty1());
        statement.setString(2, element.getProperty2());
        .....

        statement.addBatch();
        if ((i + 1) % 200 == 0) {
            statement.executeBatch(); // Execute every 200 items.
        }
    }
    statement.executeBatch();
} finally {
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { //}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {//}
}
```

}

In this case i am executing every 200 items, if you wish you can set your own. But do test it because it also depends on drivers limitation on batch operations.

Comment: `statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);` you just add `insert` SQL Statement, but i have a `delete` SQL Statement. I need put two or more type SQL statements in  a batch.

Comment: Then try keeping another `statement` for delete, and hopefully it should work because both are update statements. Also make sure you are not violating any `integrity constraints` while deleting.

Answer (score 0):

**Statement:**

### Use for general-purpose access to your database. Useful when you are using static SQL statements at runtime. The Statement interface cannot accept parameters.

**PreparedStatement:**

### Use when you plan to use the SQL statements many times. The PreparedStatement interface accepts input parameters at runtime.

**CallableStatement:**

### Use when you want to access database stored procedures. The CallableStatement interface can also accept runtime input parameters.

Comment: Stick to the regular formatting. Writing it bold and huge won't result in more attention.