# addBatch() and executeBatch() equivalent in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I would like to achieve the above using jdbctemplate.

I have the following using jdbc:

```
Connection conn = DBUtilities.getSQLConnection(); 
// get a connection
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
//create statement
stmt.addBatch(sql1);
//first sql statement to be added
stmt.addBatch(sql2);
//second sql to be added
stmt.executeBatch();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql3); 
//third sql that uses previous sql 1 and 2
```

How do I add multiple SQL (batch) with jdbctemplate?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the API? [`JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String... sql)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: Yes I have.. the problem is that it is not an update ,but multiple select statements that select into temporary tables...

Comment: AFAIK selects into a table are still considered updates, not selects.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more about what you are trying to achieve with actual Sqls and See [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899543/can-preparedstatement-addbatch-be-used-for-select-queries). Running Selects in batch shouldn't be supported at very first place.

Answer (score 0):

The following code example illustrates how to execute 3 SQL update statements in a batch using the JdbcTemplate class:

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO Users (email, pass, name) VALUES ('email0', 'pass0', 'name0')";
String sql2 = "UPDATE Users SET password='default' WHERE user_id < 10";
String sql3 = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE email = ''";
     
int[] updateCounts = template.batchUpdate(sql1, sql2, sql3);
```

As you can see, the batchUpdate() method takes an array of SQL statements as arguments, and returns an array of integer numbers indicating the number of rows affected by each query.