# Write a multi-value WHERE clause in JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

How do I translate this SQL statement into a single `PreparedStatement`?

```
SELECT id, length, shipping_no, design_no, color_no, bale_no
FROM stocks
WHERE (shipping_no, design_no, bale_no) = ANY(VALUES('search_ship-1', 'des-1', 1), ('search_ship-2', 'des-2', 26));
```

Ideally something like this:

```
SELECT id, length, shipping_no, design_no, color_no, bale_no
FROM stocks 
WHERE (shipping_no, design_no, bale_no) = ANY(VALUES(?, ?, ?));

PreparedStatement st = ...;
for (...)
    st.setString(1, ...);
    st.setString(2, ...);
    st.setInt(3, ...);

    st.addBatch();
st.executeBatch();
```

Comment: You need one `set()` call per `?` placeholder.

Comment: But `executeBatch()` does not return a `ResultSet`?

Comment: Batching is used for SQL/DML statements, not for looping query parameters, read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899543/can-preparedstatement-addbatch-be-used-for-select-queries . You have to create a single query (or multiple but put in a single statement if you want to process multiple result sets) containing all parameters in advance: if you have 3 columns per an element, and the number of elements is 10, you have to create a query made for 30 `?` parameters and set them all from 1 to 30, and then invoke `executeQuery` to obtain the result sets.

Comment: You cannot use `executeBatch` for this. You will need to add as many parameters as you want to set, and then use `executeQuery`.